# Vim ruby, rails omnicompletion: "Error loading rails environment". How do I configure vim-ruby's autocomplete to work with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, autocomplete, omnicomplete

I'm trying to get `vim-ruby`'s autocompletion working with `vim-rails`. So far, I'm able to do local keyword completion with existing methods and variables in the current file, using `<C-x><C-n>` (although prefixes for instance variables and symbols are not preserved). I'd like to be able to autocomplete Rails methods like `redirect_to` and `has_many`. However, when I try to use omni-completion to accomplish this task, e.g. `redir<C-x><C-o>`, Vim tells me:

```
Error loading rails environment
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I press `ENTER`, Vim tells me:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

`vim-ruby`'s autocompletion works for plain Ruby files, so that `Arr<C-x><C-o>` completes to `Array`, and in turn `Array.<C-x><C-o>` offers a list of methods on `Array` to choose from. When I try this in a Rails file, I get the same error as above; however, when I press `ENTER` to dismiss the error, ruby's autocompletion works as expected.

My question is, how do I properly configure `vim-ruby` so it can load the Rails environment? I assume that it's a `vim-ruby` problem and not `vim-rails` because commands like `:Econtroller <controllername>` work as expected.

My `.vimrc` contains the following:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
Plugin 'slim-template/vim-slim'
Plugin 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-rails'
Plugin 'tsaleh/vim-shoulda'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
call vundle#end()

autocmd FileType ruby set omnifunc=rubycomplete#Complete
let g:rubycomplete_buffer_loading = 1
let g:rubycomplete_classes_in_global = 1
let g:rubycomplete_rails = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further investigation, `vim-ruby` was executing the system's ruby, with which I wasn't able to get rubygems to work. I'm not absolutely sure, but I believe `vim-ruby/autoload/rubycomplete.vim` was failing at [this line](https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/blob/eafac86939f683df2adfcf78ec0eae2036fac662/autoload/rubycomplete.vim#L470) while attempting to require the `console_app` gem, which didn't exist on my system.

So I re-built vim according to the instructions [on Jon Cairns' blog](http://blog.joncairns.com/2012/09/compiling-vim-with-ruby-from-rvm-on-ubuntu/). The article references RVM, but is equally applicable to rbenv or whatever ruby you might be using.

For posterity's sake, on Ubuntu, the steps I took to do this were:

`sudo apt-get install mercurial`

`hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim && cd vim`

`./configure --with-features=HUGE --enable-pythoninterp=yes --enable-multibyte=yes --enable-rubyinterp=yes --with-ruby-command=$(which ruby) --enable-gui=gnome2 --with-x --enable-fontset`

`make`

`sudo make install`

After doing this, omni-completion in Rails works like a charm - albeit a bit slow the first time it's used.

Comment: No need to install mercurial anymore as vim is on github. the command to run before `./configure ...` is `git  clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git && cd vim`